# setColorFilter is not working correclty in custom list adapter?

Tags: android

It's been 3-4 hours and I am still not able to figure out why the color of my imageView changes automatically I have done almost everything. Here is code of getView of customListAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_adapter, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.des = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_des);
        viewHolder.like = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_like);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
        viewHolder.dislike = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dislike);
        viewHolder.iv_photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        viewHolder.iv_dislike = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_dislike);
        viewHolder.iv_like = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_like);
        viewHolder.iv_pic = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Picasso.with(context).load("url here").into(viewHolder.iv_photo);
    Picasso.with(context).load("url here").into(viewHolder.iv_pic);
    if (data.get(position).isLiked)
        viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
    if (data.get(position).isDisliked)
        viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
    viewHolder.des.setText(data.get(position).getPost_des());
    viewHolder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.like.setText(data.get(position).getLikes());
    viewHolder.dislike.setText(data.get(position).getDislikes());
    viewHolder.iv_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.image_anim));
            if (data.get(position).isLiked) {
                data.get(position).setLiked(false);
                viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            } else if (data.get(position).isDisliked) {
                data.get(position).setLiked(true);
                data.get(position).setDisliked(false);
                viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            } else {
                data.get(position).setLiked(true);

                viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
            }


        }
    });
    viewHolder.iv_dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.image_anim));
            if (data.get(position).isDisliked) {
                data.get(position).setDisliked(false);
                viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            } else if (data.get(position).isLiked) {
                data.get(position).setLiked(false);
                data.get(position).setDisliked(true);
                viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
            } else {
                data.get(position).setDisliked(true);

                viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Except setColorfilter all of my code is working properly.

Comment: show actual result, and expected result. Or at least show actual result, and explain what is wrong.

Comment: call `viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(null); viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(null)` just after two `Picasso.with(...)` calls

Comment: Thanks @pskink .. It worked .. :-)

Comment: good, you could also call `setColorFilter(null)` in the `else` branches of the first two `if`s, but...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't reset the ColorFilter when the row is reused by the others.

How about try doing this and see if it works:

```
if (data.get(position).isLiked){
    viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
}else{
    viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(null);
}

if (data.get(position).isDisliked){
    viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
}else{
    viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(null);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As @pskink told me in the comment section.

Just called `viewHolder.iv_like.setColorFilter(null);` and  `viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(null)` after `Picasso.with(context).load("url here").into(viewHolder.iv_pic);`.
And it Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

viewHolder.iv_dislike.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.green_very_light));

Answer (score 0):

You should use `imageview.getDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))`

Also, don't forget else statement in list adapter.